# Double select in list

Tags: c#, .net, linq

How can i select name in list? which is itself in list???

My struct:

```
public class Item
{
    int id;
    List<Name> names;
}

public class Name
{
    int id; 
    string name;
}

List<Item> Items;
```

code:

```
Items.Select(a => a.id = 1) //whats next
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you want all of the names in a list, you can do:

```
List<Name> matchingNames = Items.Where(a => a.id == 1).Select(a => a.names);
```

Or if you want a list of the string names from the list, you can do:

```
List<string> matchingNames = Items
    .Where(a => a.id == 1)
    .SelectMany(n => n.names)
    .Select(n => n.name)
    .ToList();
```

Then, if you're using my second statement, you can output a list in the format `item, item, item` by doing:

```
string outputtedNames = string.Join(", " + matchingNames);
```

**EDIT: As requested in comments, here's how you can get names by ID based on the Name ID:**

```
List<Name> matchingNames = Items
    .SelectMany(a => a.names)
    .Where(n => n.id == 1)
    .ToList();
```

**EDIT 2: To display name items and items that both have an ID of 1, try this:**

```
List<Name> matchingNames = Items
    .Where(a => a.id == 1)
    .SelectMany(a => a.names)
    .Where(n => n.id == 1)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: sorry for my incompetence, i want get names by id in class Item, and id in class Name))

Comment: @AlexF No problems, check my latest edit, is that what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
var result = Items.Where(a => a.id == 1 && a.names.Contains(333)).Select(a => a.names);
```

Comment: But this returns Items not name.

Answer (score 1):

For restricting result you can use `Where`, and for projection you can use `Select` on specified field:

```
var result = Items.Where(x=>x.id == 1).Select(x=>x.name).ToList();
```

Finally for getting result you should execute linq query, and this could be done with `ToList()` or `foreach` loop.